# How do we get rid of our baby's thrush?

Tags: health, newborn

Both my partner and our baby have picked up [thrush](http://www.what-is-thrush.com/).

The doctor has given us some medicine - a gloopy lotion to rub in the babies mouth and my partner was given a single table which she has taken. This has seemed fairly ineffective and it just seems to have made our baby's poop toxic. Since starting the medicines she now gets quite irritated when she fills her nappy. (This maybe coincidental, but I trust the female intuition). 
So I would prefer to stay away from the doctors and their chemicals.

All the information I can find on the internet seems to be tied to selling some anti-candida product or other, and I can't find anything specific for helping babies.

What really is the best way to get rid of our baby's thrush?

**Edit**

Our doctor changed his mind about his diagnosis and said that she didn't have thrush after all. So I have not been able to try the answers suggested here and so cannot accept any of the answers.

Comment: `So I would prefer to stay away from the doctors and their chemicals.` is a very dismissive way to refer to the entire of medical science.  Doctors (and their chemicals) have built up the current medical knowledge to levels that would be deemed supernatural only a century ago.  Neither they, nor pharmacists are quacks desparate to try out their latest magic potion on you and yours; they're highly trained professionals who have dedicated their lives to improving the lives of people.

Answer (score 3):

**Naturally carbonated spring water.**

I don't know how it works, but spring water with a high level of carbonates such as calcium carbonate in them is often an effective and completely side-effect free cure for fungal infections. Not all spring waters with high levels of carbonates are bubbly, but as I understand it all *naturally* bubbly spring waters (the ones that are fizzy straight from the ground) have high levels of carbonates.

I've tried this with Swedish water Ramlösa and French water Badoit with great success. In fact, Ramlösa is ordinated  in Sweden against thrush. You can *not* use "mineral waters" or "seltzers" or other bottled waters which are essentially filtered tap water.

Simply give them this to drink several times a day, and of they are old enough to understand rinsing and gurgling, do that as well. One doctor said, when I mentioned this, that it probably was the change in pH in the mouth. I don't know myself, I just know it works. (Also may work against dandruff and athletes foot. Really, try it!)

Comment: Thanks, our baby is still on just milk, but should soon be allowed some water so I will be able to try this soon.

Comment: @Mongus Pong: Bottled water is generally sterilized, so it should be safe. Gving it to a newborn from a bottle with a rubber did probably defeats some of the purpose as the water will go directly to the stomach without passing go, so to speak. You might want to try to wash the babies toungue with a cloth soaked in the water.

Answer (score 0):

Both of our boys had thrush multiple times. Our doctor always prescribed [Gentian Violet](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/drug-information/DR600723), which worked great, albeit a bit messy. It turns everything it touches purple, including the baby's lips.